# JDeveloper can't connect to my database

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I'm using JDev 11.1.2.3.0 (on OSX 10.8) and I try connect to an external DB.
When I try to make a connection in SQL Developer everything works fine but when I use the same connection info in JDeveloper it just doesn't want to connect.
What could be the problem?

Edit:
Exporting and importing the connection also doesn't work.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy No I'm not. But that woudln't make a difference I suppose since SQL Developer let's me connect but Jdeveloper not and I'm running it on the same system and network.

Comment: the two programs use a different connection mechanism. You can define proxy setting separately for each program by going to `Tools>Preferences>Web Browser and Proxy`. Make sure JDev has the same settings as SQLDev has

Comment: @MaVRoSCy you are a live saver! You were right, the settings weren't the same. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two programs use a different connection mechanism. You can define proxy setting separately for each program by going to Tools>Preferences>Web Browser and Proxy. Make sure JDev has the same settings as SQLDev has